# Embedding Cross-Domain Flash (swfobject)

Tags: flash, swfobject

In my site, I'm embedding a flash component using swfobject.js.My site and the .swf are not on the same domain and I suspect this causes my problem - the flash is visible on my site, but it's not responsive to any interaction (clicking it, for instance).

So my site, that is running on, let's say, `my.domain.com`, have this in the head of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {
        base: "",
        wmode: "transparent",
        scale: "noscale",
        salign: "tr"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://some.other.domain/myFlash.swf", "divIv", "100%", "500px", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);
</script>
```

The result: I see the swf but clicking it doesn't do anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Cross domain shouldn't be an issue here. Maybe there is a `<div>` overlaying Flash and capturing clicks? Or the Flash is locked and can't be used on some domains?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your console for errors?
It might also be the swf file your are loading from other sites. It might be exclusive for their domain. Try referring to this link http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?301185-AS3-cross-domain-policy

Comment: There was nothing suspicious in the console. Thanks for the link - after reading it, I believe the problem can be solved with a change in Flash itself. Anyhow, I did many tests and I'm sure it's somehow related to the domains not being the same.